# Nav bar button changes to active when scrolling to location it hrefs to

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I honestly have a hard time explaining this problem accurately. I have a navbar with some `<li>` elements one of which has a `<ul>` collection inside of it for a drop down menu. I just noticed it today but when scrolling down that page when the navbar is above the section that this specific button targets the navbar changes to `<li>` active and changes colors as according to my css.

Here is my code for the drop down menu.

```
<li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropbtn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#pricing">
                        products
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul style="list-style:none !important; padding:0px 0px !important;" class="dropdown-content">
                        <li><a ng-click="SwitchProduct(0)" href="#pricing" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">CPR-Web</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-click="SwitchProduct(1)" href="#pricing" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">SC-Tracker</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-click="SwitchProduct(2)" href="#pricing" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Keystone Jury</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I am investigating right now but the only thing I can think of is that the product on the navbar links to the section it changes to active to while above. But I still don't know why.

I also have a really hard time explaining it properly so here is a link to view the bug. Once on the page scroll down to products and see the navbar word change to active. [Link](http://ssiclouddev.azurewebsites.net/default.html)

Comment: it is because your one page logic detects that you are in the products section ... if you want I can get more in to the problem but to get you on to the right track is not your css it is you js that cause the problem.

Comment: Yeah I am still looking for the cause of this problem I just don't know where in my JS there is something changing that to active.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that for some reason having the `href="#pricing"` was the cause of the problem. So to fix that I already had my ng-click scrolling the products carousel, I just added the scrolling logic in to that instead of on the main page.

```
$scope.SwitchProduct = function (number) {

            // Store hash
            var hash = "#pricing";

            // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
            // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 900, function () {

                // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });

            $("#ProductsCycle").carousel(number);

        };
```

Also I had already created in the past a class called FakeClickable that made `<a>` links without an href tag appear as so.

```
<li class="dropdown">
                    <a  href="" class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a ng-click="SwitchProduct(0)" class="FakeClickable">CPR-Web</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-click="SwitchProduct(1)" class="FakeClickable">SC-Tracker</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-click="SwitchProduct(2)" class="FakeClickable">Keystone Jury</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```